# How to update two tables from one form yii

Tags: php, yii

I have to update two tables from one form. I have two tables TestA and TestB.
So how can I update two tables where `TestB.testid=TestA.testid`. Both the tables are populated. I need to update TestB based on the id of TestA.
Below is the `actionUpdate` of TestA.

```
  public function actionUpdate($id)
        {       $model_A=new TestA;    
                $model_B=new TestB;    
            $model=$this->loadModel($id);
            if(isset($_POST['TestA'])&&isset($_POST['TestB']))
            {
                 $model_A->attributes=$_POST['TestA'];                   
                 $model_B->attributes=$_POST['TestB'];

                 $model_B->name="test";              

                 $model_A->save();
                 $model_B->save();    
            $this->render('update',array(
                'model'=>$model,
            ));
        }
```

When I run the application, a new entry is created in TestB instead of updating the existing one. How can I pass the id to update the row in table TestB

Comment: Please take a look at your code, I bet it can benefit from better formatting.

Comment: K...will format it better

Comment: Is this the controller for TestA or TestB or neither? The `$id` that is coming in as input is that the id for TestA or TestB or neither?

Comment: @Pitchinnate I have mentioned it is a controller in Test_A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok if this is update you need to first pull the existing values from the database, then you need to make sure you send both models to the form:

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $model_A = TestA::model()->findByPk($id);
    $model_B = TestB::model()->findByAttributes(array('testid'=>$model_A->testid));
    if (isset($_POST['TestA']) && isset($_POST['TestB'])) {
        $model_A->attributes = $_POST['TestA'];
        $model_B->attributes = $_POST['TestB'];

        $model_B->name = "test";

        $model_A->save();
        $model_B->save();
    }
    $this->render('update', array(
        'model_A' => $model_A,
        'model_B' => $model_B,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Your going to have to be more descriptive if you want us to try to help you debug. What isn't working?

Comment: Meh this will work actually). I can't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Do rows already exist for TestA and for TestB? Are you updating both or updating TestA and creating a new TestB? What does your view look like? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Absolutely working fine...I had put $model_B->testid = $model_A->testid; It gave me exception

Comment: But fields in update form of testA are not getting populated with this values. Gridview is getting populated.What can I do for this

Comment: You would have to post your View, most likely you still are referencing `$model` not `$model_A` in your form.

Answer (score 0):

You can access all model properties (including the ID) after you saved it. So after you saved $model_A, $model_A->testid will contain the testid of the just saved model (model A).

```
if ($model_A->save()) {
   $model_B->testid = $model_A->testid;
   $model_B->save();
}
```

Comment: I got this exception...CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY'.

Comment: There is already a row in your database with that id and you want to insert a new row (you're creating a new model B on line 3 of your code). If you want to update model B, you should load that model first instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Can You explain me I'm new to Yii

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're in controller for Model_A and you're only updating Model_A (you're in the update action).

- First load model A
- Fill the attributes of model A with POST data
- Load model B, if not exists, create new model B
- Fill the attributes of model B with POST data
- Save model A and model B

Though it's nicer (and easier) to use relations here and put the whole model B stuff in the afterSave method of model A.

```
 public function actionUpdate($id)
        {
            $model=$this->loadModel($id);

            if(isset($_POST['TestA'])&&isset($_POST['TestB']))
            {
                 $model->attributes=$_POST['TestA'];

                 $modelB = TestB::model()->findByAttributes(array('testid'=>$model->testid));

                 if ($modelB == null) {
                   $modelB = new TestB;
                   $modelB->testid = $model->testid;
                 }

                 $model_B->attributes=$_POST['TestB'];


                 if ($model_A->save()) {
                    $model_B->save();
                 }

                $this->render('update',array(
                    'model'=>$model,
                ));
        }
```